# Spark Shell unable to read file at valid path

Tags: scala, shell, apache-spark, bigdata, cloudera

I am trying to read a file in Spark Shell that comes with CentOS distribution of Cloudera on my local machine. Following are the commands I have entered in Spark Shell.

```
spark-shell
val fileData = sc.textFile("hdfs://user/home/cloudera/cm_api.py");
fileData.count
```

I also tried this statment for reading file:

```
val fileData = sc.textFile("user/home/cloudera/cm_api.py");
```

However I am getting

```
org.apache.hadoop.mapred.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/user/cloudera/cm_api.py
```

I haven't changed any settings or configurations. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: No need for the ancient `;` in scala.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the leading slash in your url, so the path is relative. To make it absolute, use

```
val fileData = sc.textFile("hdfs:///user/home/cloudera/cm_api.py")
```

or

```
val fileData = sc.textFile("/user/home/cloudera/cm_api.py")
```

Comment: Tried `hdfs:///` it didn't work. Have to try `/user` path.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to put the file in hdfs first: `hadoop fs -put`, then check the file: `hadoop fs -ls`, then go `spark-shell`  , `val fileData = sc.textFile("cm_api.py")`

Answer (score 0):

In `"hdfs://user/home/cloudera/cm_api.py"`, you are missing the `hostname` of the URI. You should have pass something like `"hdfs://<host>:<port>/user/home/cloudera/cm_api.py"`, where `<host>` is Hadoop NameNode host and the `<port>` is, *well*, port number of Hadoop NameNode, which is `50070` by default.

Answer (score 0):

The error message says `hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/user/cloudera/cm_api.py` does not exist. The path looks suspicious! The file you mean is probably at `hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/cm_api.py`.

If it is, you can access it by using that full path. Or, if the default file system is configured as `hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/cloudera/`, you can use simply `cm_api.py`.

Comment: Isn't this`quickstart.cloudera:8020` a URL rather a directory on disk?

Comment: Nomenclature aside I think `sc.textFile("hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/home/cloudera/cm_api.py")` is your best bet. `sc.textFile("/user/home/cloudera/cm_api.py")`, and perhaps `sc.textFile("cm_api.py")` may also work.

Comment: Neither of them worked. I don't know why is it. The file is present in the Cloudera home directory.

Comment: But surely you get a different error message. What's the error when you include the full path to the file? Also, check that the file is there by `hadoop fs -ls hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/home/cloudera/cm_api.py`. If that does not work, then the file is simply not there.

Answer (score 0):

You may be confused between HDFS file paths and local file paths.  By specifying

```
hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020/user/home/cloudera/cm_api.py
```

you are saying two things:

1) there is a computer by the name "quickstart.cloudera' reachable via the network (try ping to ensure that is the case), and it is running HDFS.

2) the HDFS file system contains a file at /user/home/cloudera/cm_api.py  (try 'hdfs dfs -ls /user/home/cloudera/' to verify this

If you are trying to access a file on the local file system you have to use a different URI:

```
file:///user/home/cloudera/cm_api.py
```